# MVC not passing model data from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

This is a very basic model/view/controller and the model is not coming from the view with any data to the controller. It is probably something basic that I am missing!

Two Models:

```
Namespace Models 
    Public Class Search
        Public Property Search() As String = String.Empty
        Public Property Member() As Member = Nothing
    End Class
End Namespace

Namespace Models 
    Public Class Member
        Public Property ContactRefID() As String = String.Empty
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Controller:

```
Imports Test.Models
Imports Test.Services

Namespace Test
    Public Class HomeController
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    Function Index() As ActionResult
        Dim search As New Search
        Return View("Index", search)
    End Function

    <HttpPost()>
    Function Index(ByVal search As Search) As ActionResult
        Dim member As New Member
        Dim homeRepository As New HomeRepository
        member = homeRepository.GetMemberData(search)
        search.Member = member
        Return View("Index", search)
    End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

View:

```
@ModelType Test.Models.Search
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Search Page"
End Code
@Using Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post)    
    @<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>Search Member/Account Number:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.Search)
            <br /><br />
            <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large clrButton">
                Search
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        @*...To be filled with Search.Member data*@
    </div>
End Using
```

When I enter a member/account number in the textbox to initiate the search, the search value does not get sent to the 2nd Index function in the controller. It definitely gets called because my breakpoint inside of it gets hit, but the "ByVal search As Search" comes back as Nothing.

I know in 2013 that the get:set items are not needed for the Models, but I tried to add them and it still didn't work.

I also set a value for search.Search in the top index and the textbox gets populated with the value. But when I click the Search button, it doesn't get sent to the 2nd index function either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DefaultModelBinder` is unable to bind/recognize a property if the type has the same name - in this case `Search`. Just change the property to something else and you're good to go...

Generally it's a good practice to think through the objects you're going to create and avoid such tautology. It will be easier for you to maintain these objects if they sounds reasonable. E.g. in this case, you use the name `Search` for your class. There is no sense to name the sought value Search too. Just name it as it should - `SoughtValue`

Comment: I changed the property to FindThis (lol) and at first it didn't work. Then I right-clicked the solution and cleaned it, then it worked. Excellent! I am surprised because I have done the same thing several times (property names like the class name) and this is the first time I have had that problem. Now I know (and knowing is half the battle!)